Implementing External Login does not set IsAuthenticated to true unless I refresh the page
I have implementing external login in my NET Core 8 web application.
Ths is the callback method:
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string? returnUrl = null, string? remoteError = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new ()
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        ExternalLogins = (await signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
    };

    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState
            .AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error desde el proveedor externo: {remoteError}");

        loginViewModel.SetError(remoteError);

        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }

    // Get the login information about the user from the external login provider
    var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        ModelState
            .AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error al cargar la información del login externo.");

        loginViewModel.SetError("Error al cargar la información del login externo.");

        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }

    // If the user already has a login (i.e if there is a record in AspNetUserLogins
    // table) then sign-in the user with this external login provider
    var signInResult = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

    var userName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        if (userName != null)
        {
            await SetLastLoggedOnTime(userName);
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (user != null)
                await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
        }

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // Verifica que el usuario exista. Si existe, agrega el login y autentica
        var creado = userName == null ? null : await usuarioService.CreateUserFromExternal(userName, info);
        if (creado != null)
        {
            await userManager.AddLoginAsync(creado, info);
            await signInManager.SignInAsync(creado, isPersistent: false);
            if (userName != null)
                await SetLastLoggedOnTime(userName);

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            loginViewModel.Notification = new Integration.ViewModels.MessageViewModel
            {
                Type = Integration.ViewModels.AlertTypes.Danger
            };
            if (signInResult.IsLockedOut)
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario está bloqueado.");
            else if (signInResult.IsNotAllowed)
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario no está autorizado para ingresar.");
            else
                loginViewModel.SetError("El usuario no está registrado en la plataforma.");
        }
    }

    return View("Login", loginViewModel);
}

When user is logged in, LocalRedirect(returnUrl) redirects to a protected page. That target page thinks user is not authenticated (IsAuthenticated property is false) so, system redirects back to login page. If I immediately set the browser URL to a protected page, without trying to login again, IsAuthenticated becomes true, and the page is displayed.
What is wrong here?
Note that when I see info object after external authentication, IsAuthenticated appears true.

And also User.Identity.IsAuthenticated:

Only when the redirect is performed, the target page has User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false
I have this code in a custom AuthorizeAttribute. At this stage, I see that propety is false:

As I said, if I change the browser URL to a protected page, this is the result:

Finally, this is how I configure authentication.
var ab = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
        };
    });

string googleClientId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty;
if (googleClientId != string.Empty)
    ab.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = googleClientId;
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
        googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/Security/GoogleSignIn";
    });


string facebookAppId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Facebook:AppId"] ?? string.Empty;
if (facebookAppId != string.Empty)
    ab.AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Facebook:AppId"] ?? string.Empty;
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Facebook:AppSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
        facebookOptions.CallbackPath = "/Security/FacebookSignIn";
    });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCore";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.LoginPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authenticate/Security/AccessDenied";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
        {
            // Hice esto para que no considere el módulo en el que se encuentra el usuario
            Uri oldUri = new(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            Uri newUri = new($"{options.LoginPath}{oldUri.Query}", UriKind.Relative);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUri.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});


I tried to reproduced your issue based on your codes  as below:
var connectionString = .......;;



builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    
    
.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = "...";
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "....";
    microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";
    
});


builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCore";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.LoginPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Logout"
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authenticate/Security/AccessDenied";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
        {
            // Hice esto para que no considere el módulo en el que se encuentra el usuario
            Uri oldUri = new(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            Uri newUri = new($"{options.LoginPath}{oldUri.Query}", UriKind.Relative);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUri.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

It failed to read your claims from cookie due to SameSite policy SameSiteMode.Strict,remove
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;

keep the policy as SameSiteMode.Lax and it works
In your case,notice the Authenticate Scheme,you configured "Cookies" as the default scheme here:
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

Since you are calling signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync to accomplish external login,the default scheme should be IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme which would be configured in AddIdentity,AddDefaultIdentity.... extension method

Did you mean "failed authentication"? Problem I have is with successful authentication.

Hi,@jstuardo,I reproduced your  issue with the codes you updated,remove options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict; and it would be ok

Hello! it finally works with your suggestion. My default scheme was before JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme because I have also API's that are called from external systems authenticating by mean of bearer tokens. This change should not affect that, right? I changed it to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme thinking that this could be the problem with external login.
